# How to type the Devanagari tra letter?

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language

Please advice me some layout for Xubuntu 14.04 so that I could type Devanagari (Sanskrit) and particularly letter "tra". I have tried everything, as it seems to me, and can't find it.

Also, if you could advice me some guide of how to type joined consonants and vowels of Sanskrit, would be of a great help to me. I have found only one chart for old Bolnagri, which does not work for my current Xubuntu 14.

Comment: there should be a menu entry allowing you to see the layout.. in Nepali layout offered by Ubuntu, for _tra (त्र)_ I have to use the combination: त ‌+ ् ‌+ र   ..you can [check this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/390647/help-with-using-nepali-unicode-keyboard-layout-romanized-and-language-suppor) too..

Comment: See [Hindi keyboard not working properly in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179099/hindi-keyboard-not-working-properly-in-ubuntu) and [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)

Answer (score 2):

Typing of Hindi joint letter "tra" (First Letter of Ta + Ra):

1. First type letter <kbd>Ta</kbd> (First letter Ta)
2. Press <kbd>NumLock</kbd> Key.
3. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0170</kbd>
4. Now you will get Hindi "Tra" joint letter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure if this helps, but if you install the *ibus-m17n* package and relogin, additional Sanskrit input method options will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had installed IBus, but apparently my system doesn't see it. I have set Harward-Kyoto and IAST on Ibus, but when I swith between languges with Ctrl+Space I still have only US and RU which were set earlier. Do you have any Idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SashaKud: No, I can't tell what's wrong. But please note that _ibus_ and _ibus-m17n_ are different packages. The latter is an input engine with several scripts, including a few Sanskrit. You may want to try it.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and was struggling to find Inscript keyboard for Hindi. Your answer helped me. Installed ibus-m17n package and inscript appeared. Works like charm now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To type tra (त्र) you have to type त+्+र on the keyboard. If you are using the Inscript layout, then you have to shift on the devanagari input and type l+d+j. The d (्) acts as a viraama and removes the "a" (scwha) and joins the following consonant with the previous one. The key is indicated with orange in the screenshot below.

You can see the keyboard layout if you have selected "Show current input source in the menu bar" in the System Settings > Text Entry settings.

[image: Devavagari keyboard layout chart]
[image: Text Entry settings dialog]