# How to install nepali unicode traditional font in ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-font-family

I have installed Nepali font int my pc with the help of this page [Help with using Nepali Unicode Keyboard Layout ( Romanized ) and Language Support!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390647/help-with-using-nepali-unicode-keyboard-layout-romanized-and-language-suppor)  and unicode romanized is installed I want to convert Nepali Romanized into Nepali Traditional. It would be great if anyone give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of IBus.

- Install the [`ibus-m17n`](https://github.com/ibus/ibus-m17n/) package:

  ```
   sudo apt install ibus-m17n
  ```
- Relogin
- Go to *System Settings -> Text Entry* and add **Nepali (trad (m17n)) (Ibus)**.